# Optimally allocating a resource with time-varying demand and cost

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, dynamic-programming, memoization

I'm working on the following DP which finds the optimal way to allocate a resource. At each time step I can either allocate (0.2 resources) at cost C or not in which case the storage is reduced by the demand. The cost C depends on which time step I do the allocation.

I need to add quite a few more complex features, but this is the bare working version in Python 2.7:

```
from math import floor
import numpy as np
import time      


def discretise(x,levels = 40,Hmax = 2, Hmin = 0):
    # discretise the levels of storage
    factor = levels / (Hmax-Hmin)
    return floor(x*factor)/factor

# function to track the storage evolution at the stages
def record(D,key,item):
    """Records the value of item in the dictionary d with k"""
    if key in D.keys():
        D[key].append(item)
    else:
        D[key] = [item]

    return D

# Memoization decorator i found online that works
def memoize(f):
    cache = {}

    def memoizedFunction(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = f(*args)
        return cache[args]

    memoizedFunction.cache = cache
    return memoizedFunction

# define demands and cost (Energy)
D = [0.1, 0.1, 0.13, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1]
Energy  = [2.0, 5.0,  9.0, 3.0, 7.0, 4.0, 6.0]



@memoize
def val(h,i=0):
    if h < 0 or h > 2: # h < Hmin or h > Hmax:
        return 1000000000
    elif i == T:  # i = T
        return -h*5 # h*m the linear value of h at i = T
    else:
        #           pump off         pump on    
        record(H,i,discretise(h))  

        no_pump = val(discretise(h-D[i]),i+1) # don't allocate
        pump = Energy[i] + val(discretise(h+0.2-D[i]),i+1) # allocate


        v = min(no_pump  , pump   )

        # record optimal policy 
        if v == no_pump:
            pos = 0
        else:
            pos = 1

        record(X,i+1,pos)
        record(V,i+1,v)


        return v


T = 7
H = {}
V = {}
X = {}
ts = time.time()
for ii in xrange(0,20):
    print val(ii/10.0)

te = time.time()

print te - ts
```

How can I get this code nicer / more pythonic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Styling

I don't think PEP8 actually says anything about this, but I prefer to have spaces after commas in just about anything.  The comma is a way of separating two items, but sometimes it just isn't enough and other times it just looks squashed without the space.  You should not, however, put spaces around the `=` sign in all cases.  From [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations):

> Don't use spaces around the `=` sign when used to indicate a keyword argument or a default parameter value.

You break that rule in the definition of `discretise()`.

Again from [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables):

> Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

That is under the title `Method Names and Instance Variables`.  Classes should be [PascalCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), but your variables should be as defined above.  Your variables, `T`, `H`, `V`, and `X` should have more descriptive names besides the fact that they should be lowercase.  I realize that you use `v` in `val()`, but if you gave more descriptive names to your variables, there wouldn't be a clash.

> ```
> v = min(no_pump  , pump   )
> ```

What are you doing with all that whitespace?  It should look like this:

```
v = min(no_pump, pump)
```

You have many cases of things such as `i+1`, `ii/10.0`, etc.  PEP8 doesn't actually say anything against that, but my opinion is that you should use whitespace around the operators unless it makes something look confusing.  For example, `a*b + c*d` would look confusing if there were spaces around the asterisks, but in the case of `val(ii/10.0)`, for example, I would prefer it to be `val(ii / 10.0)`.

## The logic

> ```
> def record(D,key,item):
>     if key in D.keys():
>         D[key].append(item)
>     else:
>         D[key] = [item]
> ```

That function could be simplified to this:

```
def record(D, key, item):
    D.setdefault(key, []).append(item)
```

Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault).  If you wanted to leave it how it was, though, you could still take out the `.keys()` part of the `if` statement.  Turning a dictionary into an iterator, which `in` does, turns it into an iterator of its keys.

> ```
> def memoize(*args):
>     cache = {}
>
>     def memoizedFunction(*args):
>         if args not in cache:
>             cache[args] = f(*args)
>         return cache[args]
>
>     memoizedFunction.cache = cache
>     return memoizedFunction
> ```

Using `memoizedFunction.cache = cache` isn't helping you here.  You aren't even using it.  You might be better off defining a class:

```
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if args not in self.cache:
            self.cache[args] = self.function(*args)
        return self.cache[args]
```

I changed the name to `Memoize` to comply with PEP8, but that just means that you need to change `@memoize` to `@Memoize`.

> ```
>         #           pump off         pump on
> ```

It isn't clear to me what that comment is saying.  The `pump on` part goes beyond the end of the next line.  If you meant it to be a comment on a different line, you should move it.

> ```
> v = min(no_pump  , pump   )
>
> # record optimal policy 
> if v == no_pump:
>     pos = 0
> else:
>     pos = 1
> ```

Here would be a good use of the [cmp()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=cmp#cmp) function:

```
v = cmp(no_pump, pump)
if v <= 0:
    pos = 0
else:
    pos = 1
```

> ```
> ts = time.time()
> ...
> te = time.time()
> ```

I can tell from the last line, `print te - ts` that those are meant to stand for `time start` and `time end`, but why not spell it out?  In this case it's fairly easy to tell what they are for, but it's a good habit to make your variable names very clear.  I would define them as `start_time` and `end_time`.